# Google App Script Regex on subject in for loop

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I'm trying to apply a regex to extract data from the subject of several mails (from a label).
I only get a result every other mail? The regex is correct, I tested all subjects against the pattern with an online tool.

Anyone an idea what's wrong? I have tried a dozen things, but no luck.

Code

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   var msg = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
   var body = msg.getBody();
   var subject = msg.getSubject();
   Logger.log("#" + subject + "#");
   var re = /Week (\d{1,2})\s?[-:]\s?(.*?)$/gi;
   var match = re.exec(subject);
   Logger.log(match);
   if (match) { 
      Logger.log(match[1] + '---' + match[2]);
   }
}
```

Log

```
[16-08-24 10:36:38:003 CEST] #Week 25 - Samosa aardappel koriander#
[16-08-24 10:36:38:004 CEST] [Week 25 - Samosa aardappel koriander, 25, Samosa aardappel koriander]
[16-08-24 10:36:38:005 CEST] 25---Samosa aardappel koriander
[16-08-24 10:36:38:156 CEST] #Week 24 - Pebre#
[16-08-24 10:36:38:156 CEST] null
[16-08-24 10:36:42:318 CEST] #Week 23 - Caramel chocolade shortbread#
[16-08-24 10:36:42:319 CEST] [Week 23 - Caramel chocolade shortbread, 23, Caramel chocolade shortbread]
[16-08-24 10:36:42:319 CEST] 23---Caramel chocolade shortbread
[16-08-24 10:36:42:491 CEST] #Week 22 - Bretzel#
[16-08-24 10:36:42:492 CEST] null
[16-08-24 10:36:42:674 CEST] #Week 21 - Basilicum quenelles#
[16-08-24 10:36:42:675 CEST] [Week 21 - Basilicum quenelles, 21, Basilicum quenelles]
[16-08-24 10:36:42:675 CEST] 21---Basilicum quenelles
```

When I start with i = 1 I get

```
[16-08-24 10:38:44:158 CEST] #Week 24 - Pebre#
[16-08-24 10:38:44:159 CEST] [Week 24 - Pebre, 24, Pebre]
[16-08-24 10:38:44:159 CEST] 24---Pebre
[16-08-24 10:38:44:307 CEST] #Week 23 - Caramel chocolade shortbread#
[16-08-24 10:38:44:307 CEST] null
[16-08-24 10:38:46:463 CEST] #Week 22 - Bretzel#
[16-08-24 10:38:46:463 CEST] [Week 22 - Bretzel, 22, Bretzel]
[16-08-24 10:38:46:463 CEST] 22---Bretzel
[16-08-24 10:38:46:616 CEST] #Week 21 - Basilicum quenelles#
[16-08-24 10:38:46:616 CEST] null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a matter of using a global modifier or not in your case.

See

```
var re = /Week (\d{1,2})\s?[-:]\s?(.*?)$/gi;
var match = re.exec(subject);
```

Your regex contains a global modifier `g` that, when used with [`RegExp#exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), advances the RegExp `lastIndex` with each successful match.

> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the `exec()` method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. When you do so, the **search starts at the substring of `str` specified by the regular expression's `lastIndex` property** (`test()` will also advance the `lastIndex` property).

Since you are using `exec` to only get one match at a time, the `g` modifier is redundant.

The solution is simply to remove `g` (and I'd suggest using `*` quantifier after `\s` to handle multiple whitespaces if any, and replace `.*?` with `.*` at the end to grab all the rest of the line in 1 go without checking each char):

```
var re = /Week (\d{1,2})\s*[-:]\s*(.*)/i;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to reset the last index of the regex (this have been a really painfull for me to discover when I got the same trouble)

```
re.lastIndex = 0;
```

Here your code with the modif:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   var msg = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
   var body = msg.getBody();
   var subject = msg.getSubject();
   Logger.log("#" + subject + "#");
   var re = /Week (\d{1,2})\s?[-:]\s?(.*?)$/gi;
   re. lastIndex = 0;
   var match = re.exec(subject);
   Logger.log(match);
   if (match) { 
      Logger.log(match[1] + '---' + match[2]);
   }
}
```

for further understanding have a look at this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: You need to reset the lastindex of the regex even if you re create the var at each loop (don't ask me why)

Comment: Thanks! You just save me a couple more hours of cursing ;-)

Comment: No need to reset anything, just use `var re = /Week (\d{1,2})\s?[-:]\s?(.*?)$/i;` - without `/g`. Then you can remove `re.lastIndex = 0;`. Just use what you need, no more, no less, and your code will stay efficient and succint.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are right, in this case it's better to remove the "g"